# setting up footer width

Tags: html, css, layout, footer

Hello I have the following problem. I embedded my footer with a width and height. Up to this point the footer didn't have a background color. Now I thought it would be to have the footer stretch across the entire width and giving it a background color.

My problem is, that I don't know how to make it possible to get that footer filled with a color that will easily simply said "reapeat-x" that color. I did it with my background `body`. I cannot easily create an image because the content of the main page is not fixed to one height. I also would like to know how to realize that the footer of this example will stay on bottom?

I found an example where you can see what I mean when you resize the solution on this page:

http://razzi.me/tour

Hope this makes it clear what I am trying to achieve. I really would appreciate if there is someone who could help me out.

thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, but this only fills the color. that is not the problem. the problem i got is that i have a fixed width when using background-color.

Comment: do you want to have it so that your background only fills a certain width of your footer, not the whole thing?

Comment: i'm sorry. i gave not enough information. i have my mainwrapper of the site limited to 960px. in that mainwrapper i have embedded my footer. so this is the reason why i only can see 960px width filled with background-color. i would like to have whole width to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this effect, you need to place your footer outside the wrapper. I typically use this [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto -50px;
    width: 960px;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 50px;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KDYX/

Comment: hi, i tried using this example. i still have problems with my hidden divs. in case of open a trigger, the footer wont move to the end of the page. it will cross the hidden div. i have a fixed div of 476px. after that there is another div that will be displayed when a button is pressed.

Comment: @bonny. Can you show me your code more specifically? Creating a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your source code would be ideal for me to help you.

Comment: i forgot about the anchors in the hidden div. that div will come up when opening that div.

Comment: @bonny. You failed to add the push div to your HTML and your CSS. Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cuee/2/

Comment: okay, i tried to do so. two problems left. first one will be that i have some container in my footer. with .footer, .push that will both give a background color and it seems like the push class overlays the footer with the containers so that it is just grey in color. second problem will be when resizing the page the footer will stay on ground and the push class will be wander away from the footer.

Comment: third problem is the space between the footer and the second div. as you can see http://jsfiddle.net/9Cuee/2/ there will be a bit of the red hidden div visible. this should not be visible so that the footer needs to be higher to avoiding this red visible div on that unopened status.

Comment: here is the example with anchor, but it seems like jsfiddle can not display that: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cuee/4/

Comment: The issue with the extra red space is coming from `#mainframe {     padding-bottom: 80px; }`. Also, just remove the color from the `.push` div. That was an error on my part, just apply it to `.footer`. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cuee/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14149/discussion-between-jsw189-and-bonny)

Comment: OMG... i found so many ways to get a sticky footer and tried a lot of them that i forgot about that to delete. thank you very much. thats it. have a nice day. bye

Answer (score 1):

I exactly don't know what layout you are having in your code but if you want to have full-width footer and contents to be of 960px you can do set the layout as:

```
<body>
   <div id="header">

       <div class="wrapper">

       </div>

   </div>

   <div id="container" class="wrapper">

       //your container with 960px width

   </div>

   <div id="footer">

       <div class="wrapper">

       </div>

   </div>
</body>
<!-- I suggested to have a wrapper in header and footer so that
     your text or links or whatever you have could be in 960px width
     but your header and footer backgrounds spawns to full-width
-->
```

and the CSS would be something:

```
body { width:100% }

#header, #footer { width:100% }

.wrapper { width:960px }

#footer { clear:both; height:100px; bottom:0; display:block; background-color:#555; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the footer background color extend to 100% width of the window, it will have to move out of your mainwrapper. Something like:

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
    stuff goes here
</div>
<div id="footerwrapper">
    <footer>
      Stuff goes here
    </footer>
</div>
```

Then, in CSS:

```
#mainwrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footerwrapper {
    background-color: blue /* or whatever */;
}

footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```